# How to get data by 4 characters, not 1 from the loop?

Tags: c++

I would like the variable i to produce 4 characters.

```
1239 2121 4511 7457 2562
```

code:

```
string test1 = "12392121451174572562";

int64_t test2 = 1239212145117457;
```

here is a ready-made example, but I don’t like it, it will work slowly, can it be improved?

```
int num = 0;
for (char i : test1) 
{
    cout << i;
    if (++num == 4)
    {
        cout << " ";
        num = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: "t, it will work slowly, " have you measured it? Is it really a problem? I highly suspect no.

Comment: "it will work slowly" - *Don't optimize before you profile your code.* Stream operations are buffered and until you make something stupid (like adding `std::endl`) this is as fast as it can be.

Comment: _"Can it be improved?"_ Perhaps better suited to [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Although there are certainly some obvious optimizations here, I doubt that you can tell the difference with modern multi-Ghz CPUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you said:

> it will work slowly

I think you want better code. This may not be the best way, but it should be closer to what you want:

```
string test1 = "12392121451174572562";
for (int i = 0; i < test1.length(); i++)
{
    if (i % 4 == 0)
        cout << " ";
    cout << test1[i];
}
```

Comment: *but i think u mean u want better coding for this* -- Please do not respond using short-hand text messaging.  Persons whose native language is not English will be reading your response, or trying to read it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i'm typing like this cuz my english is bad ( my native languish is arabic not english ), also i think even who's not native languish  is englsih will understand this , cuz after all the code is talking not me .

Comment: So you can't type "you" instead of "u"?  I'm sure there is a posting guideline somewhere that states that answers should be in as best English as possible.

Comment: Oh i got you , i though u talking about the whole my answer xD , ok i will keep this in my mind in the future

Comment: I am not on a timer, sorry.

Comment: @Peilonrayz the idea of his comments so i can learn , so in the future i don't do same mistake , if he just changed my post he will do it tons of times for every my future answers .

Comment: I liked the idea with `if (i% 4 == 0)`
I don’t know if it will work faster but it looks better.